# String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated while removing data

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a `PriceId` and I get some `PriceGaranties` by it and I am trying to delete `PriceGaranties` by updating `Price` and see this error.

Here is the code:

```
public void DeletePriceGaranties(int priceId)
{
    var deletedPriceGaranties = context.PriceGaranties.Where(p => p.PriceId == priceId).ToList();
    foreach (var priceGaranty in deletedPriceGaranties)
    {
        context.PriceGaranties.Remove(priceGaranty);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The error is:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

**Update**

Here are the models:

```
public class Price
{
    public int PriceId { get; set; }
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public int ClassPartnerId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdate { get; set; }
    public bool Enable { get; set; }
    public int CostTypeId { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Class Class { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<OldPrice> OldPrices { get; set; }
    public List<PriceColor> PriceColors { get; set; }
    public List<PriceGaranty> PriceGaranties { get; set; }
    public ClassPartner ClassPartner { get; set; }
}

public class PriceGaranty
{
    public int PriceGarantyId { get; set; }
    public int PriceId { get; set; }
    public int GarantyId { get; set; }
    public Comparing.Model.Price.Price Price { get; set; }
}
```

And all of string types are nvarchar(MAX).

Comment: Can you show us the properties of the classes? There is a string property which you need to change the mapping configuration for a larger length of string.

Comment: Make sure the data length of each property in `PriceGaranties` are same as in the database table.

Comment: You have specified the length of the string in your database to be shorter than what you are trying to add to it. E.g. you may have set your varchar length in the database to be of length 10 but the string you want to add is 11, 15, 20 etc characters. The database doesnt know what to do with it so it just cuts off the excess characters. Try setting your field length in your database to a larger length. Also not to be a stickler for spelling but you misspelled Guarantee's as garanties. Unless that word means something else?? haha.

Comment: @KyleT The problem occur when it is removing PriceGaranties in a foreach loop but I set all string types for price to nvarchar(MAX) and nothing happend!

Comment: Open up sql profiler in sql server under the Tools menu. Once opened place a breakpoint on the code which executes the SQL script and step into the code until the script has ran. This technique will tell you where in your SQL script the code is breaking. Can you take a screenshot of your database schema for us? That way we can see what data might be truncated.

Comment: @KyleT Yeah. You are right. I understood it later when The Garanty word was repeated thousands of times in the application.:))
I found the issue. One column in one of the related tables to price was nvarchar(200) and the input length was more than 200. But why it was showing error after updating the column value in next lines, I dont know.:))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified the length of the string in your database to be shorter than what you are trying to add to it. E.g. you may have set a varchar length in your database to be of length 10 but the string you want to add is 11, 15, 20 etc characters. The database doesnt know what to do with it so it just cuts off the excess characters. Try setting the field length in your database to a larger length.

[image: This image provides an example of how truncation works in SQL server.]

Comment: The "Your database" heading on the table should really read "Your database table" my bad.

Comment: Thank you for spending time.